# Get code from overriden method in anonymous declaration

Tags: java, overriding, anonymous-methods

Is there a way to auto-generate code when anonymously declare a new instance of abstract class, thanks in advance.

Here's is an example :

**My abstract class :**

```
public abstract class MySqlQueryHelperCallback {

    /**
     *
     * @param rs ResultSet for precedent sql request
     */
    protected void queryResult(ResultSet rs)
    {
        try
        {
            while (rs.next())
            {
                //Whatever
            }
        } catch (SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    };
}
```

**What happens when i anonymously create an instance :**

```
test.executeQuery("SELECT *  FROM visiteur", new MySqlQueryHelperCallback() {
    @Override
    protected void queryResult(ResultSet rs)
    {
        super.queryResult(rs);
    }
});
```

**What i would like to happens :**

```
test.executeQuery("SELECT *  FROM visiteur", new MySqlQueryHelperCallback() {
    @Override
    protected void queryResult(ResultSet rs)
    {
        try
        {
            while (rs.next())
            {
                //Whatever
            }
        } catch (SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: This will not be possible with just Java. If there is a way to make this work, it'll be with your IDE so I suggest you edit that in.

Comment: you can make 'whatever' in to an abstract method. so anonymous implementation only has to implement that method without overriding queryResult.

Comment: damn, i'd think there is an other way to do this

Comment: @DevBlanked i got your point, but this is not what i want :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Java language does not support auto-generation.

Rather, auto-generation is / would be implemented by a tool such as your IDE.  So what you should be doing is look at your IDE's mechanisms for auto-generating code.  These will depend on what IDE you are using.

For example, in Eclipse, you can define custom code templates to do this kind of thing.